# Android custom keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Hello I am working on `Custom KEYBOARD` for my app.

i.e

```
<Keyboard
         android:keyWidth="%10p"
         android:keyHeight="50px"
         android:horizontalGap="2px"
         android:verticalGap="2px" >
     <Row android:keyWidth="32px" >
         <Key android:keyLabel="A" />
         ...
     </Row>
     ...
 </Keyboard>
```

I want to know is there any method or android tag available for **set invisible or visible** the keyboard board `key`.

like `android:visibility="gone" or setVisibility(View.GONE)` for `Keyboard` layout.

Cause in my app there are many variation in Keyboard.

any information regarding this.

Comment: ya its good link..i ll give it try. thanks .but i don't know i ll get my requirement or not. but thanks again.

Comment: Absolutely it is possible to make like this. you must to modified your LatinKeyboard behavior of that key which one you want to visibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hide a key by changing the width of a key.

The following is an example of hiding language-switch key:

```
void setLanguageSwitchKeyVisibility(boolean visible) {
    if (visible) {
        // The language switch key should be visible. Restore the size of the mode change key
        // and language switch key using the saved layout.
        mModeChangeKey.width = mSavedModeChangeKey.width;
        mModeChangeKey.x = mSavedModeChangeKey.x;
        mLanguageSwitchKey.width = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.width;
        mLanguageSwitchKey.icon = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.icon;
        mLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview = mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview;
    } else {
        // The language switch key should be hidden. Change the width of the mode change key
        // to fill the space of the language key so that the user will not see any strange gap.
        mModeChangeKey.width = mSavedModeChangeKey.width + mSavedLanguageSwitchKey.width;
        mLanguageSwitchKey.width = 0;
        mLanguageSwitchKey.icon = null;
        mLanguageSwitchKey.iconPreview = null;
    }
}
```

Edit `LatinKeyboard` to hide a key.